# How to prevent Router to consider different route as route parameters?

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I'm trying to get this routing to work correctly; I have lazy-loaded feature module, I have implemented a routing module in it as well, which looks like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'users/:id', component: UsersEditComponent, canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard]},
    { path: 'users', component: UsersComponent, canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard] },
    { path: 'processes', redirectTo: '/home' },
    { path: 'new-optimization-item', component: NewItemComponent },
    { path: '', component: AdminConsoleComponent,
        children: [
            { path: ':item-id', component: AdminSearchComponent},
            { path: ':item-id/:actionId', component: AdminActionComponent },
        ],
        canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard] }
];
```

Now, in `AdminConsoleComponent` I have a routerLink that navigates to `admin/new-optimization-item`, the thing is, when I click that link, I get sent to the correct component, but it also takes both segments of the URL as parameters for`item-id` and `actionId`, so all the services that use that information actually trigger because I imagine, the application is actually loading the `AdminSearchComponent` first.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening and just navigate to the route without using `new-optimization-item` as parameter?

Comment: Change the order of the children to route to the most specific first?

Comment: Already did, the same happens of course because when I try to navigate to `/new-optimization-item`, the router takes that string as a parameter for `:item-id`